# assign value to function object

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I have a object called DummyObject with a property called 'value' I am 
trying to assign a value through the function 'assignValue' but it shows up undefined after I try to assign it.  I am assuming that in the 'assignValue' function the 'v' should be pointing to 'this.value' and when i assign it to that it should update 'this.value'.

```js
function DummyObject(){
    this.value;
}

DummyObject.prototype.assignValue = function(val){
    var v = this.value;
    v = {val: val};
}

var dObj = new DummyObject();
dObj.assignValue(23);

console.log(dObj);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables in JavaScript don't work that way. When you create the variable `v` with

```
var v = this.value;
```

you create something that's completely independent from `this.value`, not an alias to `this.value`. If you want to change `this.value` you have to do so directly.

```
this.value = {val: val};
```

Answer (score 2):

References are kept for objects but `this.value` is undefined (non-object) so it won't work as you're thinking it would. Initialize it with an object and that will work by modifying the specific property.

```js
function DummyObject() {
    this.value = {};
}

DummyObject.prototype.assignValue = function(val) {
    var v = this.value;
    v.val = val;
}

var dObj = new DummyObject();
dObj.assignValue(23);

console.log(dObj); // {value: {value: 23}}
```

However, the best way would be to modify `this.value` directly.

```
this.value = {val: val};
```

Answer (score 0):

JS doesn't reserve your pointer if you ever say:

`thing = newThing`

Your local variable `v` is no longer pointing at this.value, so just drop that variable altogether. If you want to set a bunch of things, you can use an object, which is passed by reference:

```
function DummyObject() {
  this.value;
}

DummyObject.prototype.assignValue = function(val) {
  var v = this.value = { val: val };
  v.somethingElse = 'someData';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `prototype.toString` for making a custom object value.  I think there might be issues with it since I don't see it used very often.  You may want to use `dObj.value` to avoid any problems.

```js
function DummyObject(){
    this.value;
}

DummyObject.prototype.assignValue = function(val){
    this.value = val;
};

DummyObject.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.value;
};

var dObj = new DummyObject();
dObj.assignValue(23);

var out = document.getElementById('out');

out.innerHTML += dObj;
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```